# 5V Tolerant I/O

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, io

A  lot of micro-controllers has 5V Tolerant I/O pins using lower supply voltages (For example 3.3V). Even when they can't drive more than 3.3V at the output, they can be used in open-drain configuration for tri-state operation (useful for I2C)

What is the real advantage of it? Is there so many external interfaces operating in 5V to make it attractive for the market? Does it apply for IoT devices?

Thanks!

Comment: Most? *citation required*

Comment: For some logic families logic 'high' and 'low' are quite a wide range.  TTL for example will accept anything above 2V as a 'high' so if you are a 5V tolerant device you can work with TTL even if you are 3.3V powered device.  Most does need clarification however. Is this by number of products, number of sales, cost of sales or something else and what is your source for this. Probably should have gone with 'A lot of' which I can't argue with.

Comment: One thing that comes immediately to mind is that, if it is not 5V tolerant, any mistake will potentially fry your chip. At least for the hobby stand point, it's not a good thing.

Comment: it seems 5v was a defacto for a long time, now 3.3v is becoming more common. through the transition, 5v tolerant makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the real advantage of 5v tolerant I/O?

It expands the market. It means that there are more potential customers for a 3.3v microcontroller that has this feature, than one that doesn't. Which means more sales, more profits etc.

It's also fairly easy to provide this feature, you just leave out or modify the output to V+ ESD protection diode to allow the outputs to be pulled up to 5v. The I/O transistors are usually different to the core transistors, beefier and higher voltage as they're user-facing, so will probably handle 5v anyway.